# Engineering applications of the Rank-Nullity Theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples, education

The Rank-Nullity Theorem in Linear Algebra can be stated as follows:

> Let ${\displaystyle T:V\to W} $ be a linear transformation between two vector spaces where ${\displaystyle T}$'s domain ${\displaystyle V}$ is finite dimensional. Then
>
> $$ \mbox{Rank} (T)~+~\mbox{Nullity} (T)~=~\dim V. $$

For an invited talk that I shall be delivering soon, I like to give some engineering applications of Rank-Nullity Theorem, and I can't think of anything quickly.

One simple application is the homogeneous system
$$
A x = 0 \tag{$\star$}
$$
where $A$ is of size $m \times n$. Then Rank-Nullity Theorem can be applied for the linear map $T(x) = A x$ to deduce that the system ($\star$) admits only the trivial solution $x = 0$ if and only if $A$ has full column rank.

Similarly, using Rank-Nullity Theorem, we can easily establish the following:

The linear system
$$
A x = b, \ \ \ (A \in R^{m \times n}, \ \ b \in R^n)
$$
has a unique solution for every $ b \in R^n$ if and only if $A$ has full column rank.

I look forward to some more interesting applications, which are at a comprehensive level for the college students.

Comment: Well it is used in lots of linear algebra results and linear algebra is used intensively in engineering science..

Comment: It might be helpful to look at applications of invertible matrices to engineering where the matrices HAVE to be invertible, then rank-nullity lets you evaluate if a matrix is possibly invertible in the first place

Comment: One immediate application is in inverse kinematics - the nullity in this context refers to the dimensionality of the space of configurations of your mechanism that result in the same end effector position.

Comment: Far from engineering application, but let me just point out that rank-nullity theorem is a special case of the First Isomorphism Theorem. Perhaps this broader view can inspire some applications.